# Building a responsive site and the menu is disappearing at times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm developing a responsive website for a client using CSS media queries. Everything is going great, except when scaling the website back up after I scale it down to the lowest.

**Here is the exact problem:**

- The horizontal menu displays at full width.  Everything works fine.
- I scale it down to my condensed site, everything works fine. Horizontal menu still works.
- When I scale it down to my scalable version, I have the menu disappearing and a "menu" link appearing. That works fantastically. If I don't hover over the menu link to make the menu appear, I can scale back up and the menu works fine. **However, if I hover over menu, the menu drops down below it, and then when I scale back up, the menu is gone. It doesn't reappear.**

**Here is the code:**

*Full Version:*

```
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 940px) {
#header_whitebox .nav { position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 260px; display: block; float: left; height: 75px; }
#header_whitebox .nav ul { font-size: 1em; line-height: 1.2em; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; }
#header_whitebox .nav ul li { display: block; position: relative; float: left; min-width: 100px; }
#header_whitebox .nav ul li a { display: block; text-decoration: none; color: #282828; padding: 28px 20px; white-space: nowrap; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; letter-spacing: 1px;  }
#header_whitebox .nav ul li:hover a { color: #2C59A7; }

/* SUB NAVIGATION */
#header_whitebox .nav li ul { display: none; position: relative; border-top: 1px solid #ccc; }
#header_whitebox .nav li:hover ul { display: block; position: absolute; z-index: 100; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#header_whitebox .nav li:hover li { float: none; font-size: 13px; margin-left: -1px;  min-width: 100%; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; border-left: 1px solid #ccc; border-right: 1px solid #ccc; }
#header_whitebox .nav li:hover li a { display: block; text-decoration: none; color: #282828; padding: 10px 11px; white-space: nowrap; text-align: left; text-decoration: none; letter-spacing: 1px;  min-width: 200px; background: #fff; }
#header_whitebox .nav li:hover li:hover a {  color: #2C59A7; }
}
```

*Condensed Version:*

```
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 744px)
and (max-width : 939px) {
#header_whitebox .nav { position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 200px; display: block; float: left; height: 61px; }
#header_whitebox .nav ul { font-size: .8em; line-height: 1em; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; position: static; display: inline; }
#header_whitebox .nav ul li { display: block; position: relative; float: left; min-width: 75px; border: 0; }
#header_whitebox .nav ul li a { display: block; text-decoration: none; color: #282828; padding: 24px 15px 25px 15px; white-space: nowrap; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; letter-spacing: 1px;  }
#header_whitebox .nav ul li:hover a { color: #2C59A7; }
}
```

*Scalable Version:*

```
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 743px)
and (min-width : 481px) {
#header_whitebox .nav { display: none; position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0; height: 75px; }
#header_whitebox .nav ul { font-size: 1em; line-height: 1.2em; list-style: none; display: block; position: absolute; z-index: 100; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#header_whitebox .nav ul li { float: none; font-size: 13px; margin-left: -1px;  min-width: 100%; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; border-left: 1px solid #ccc; border-right: 1px solid #ccc; }
#header_whitebox .nav ul li a { display: block; text-decoration: none; color: #282828; padding: 10px 11px; white-space: nowrap; text-align: left; text-decoration: none; letter-spacing: 1px;  min-width: 200px; background: #fff;  }
#header_whitebox .nav ul li:hover a { color: #2C59A7; }

/* SUB NAVIGATION */
#header_whitebox .nav li ul { display: none; position: relative; border-top: 1px solid #ccc; }
#header_whitebox .nav li:hover ul { display: block; position: absolute; z-index: 100; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#header_whitebox .nav li:hover li { float: none; font-size: 13px; margin-left: -1px;  min-width: 75px; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; border-left: 1px solid #ccc; border-right: 1px solid #ccc; }
#header_whitebox .nav li:hover li a { display: block; text-decoration: none; color: #282828; padding: 10px 11px; white-space: nowrap; text-align: left; text-decoration: none; letter-spacing: 1px;  min-width: 200px; background: #fff; }
#header_whitebox .nav li:hover li:hover a {  color: #2C59A7; }
}
```

*Here is the jQuery for drop down*

```
$("#menu_button").hover(function(){
    $('.nav').slideToggle();
});
```

*Here is the HTML*

```
<a id="menu_button" class="hidecontent_full hidecontent_condensed" href="#">Menu</a>

<div class="nav fixedright">
<ul>
<li class="first"><a href="#">New?</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Welcome</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Who We Are</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">What We Believe</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">When and Where</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Crossroads Staff</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Next Steps</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">What is Next Steps?</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Connect</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Grow</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Serve</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Ministries</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Childrens Ministry</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Student Ministry</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Connect Groups</a>
    <li><a href="#">Music Ministry</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Prayer Groups</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Resources</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Sermon Archives</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Church Community Builder</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Parents</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bible Reading Plans</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Recommended Books</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="last"><a href="#">Events</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Fall Festival Campout</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Let's Paint</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Dinner for 8</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Calendar of Events</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Give</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">How to Give</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Give Online</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>

</ul>
</div>  <!-- navigation -->
```

I'm doing something wrong, I just don't know what. I tried adding `display: inline` and `display: block` to the bigger versions just to see if that would reverse it. I'm not sure if the `.slideToggle` is adding a CSS value that I'm just not reversing or what.

Comment: It may be helpful to include your media queries, too.

Comment: Maybe try postion:fixed on the scalable version.  I do something similar on mine.

Comment: It would also helpful to see your HTML structure. What I am guessing is the absolute positioning is putting the menu some place off screen.

Comment: @TylerH - I added Media Queries.    @Marty McKeever - But the problem is, `position: fixed;` won't actually do what I want it to...because in the end, my scalable menu is going to be fully javascript based...but I'm just trying to figure out why the menu is disappearing in the bigger versions.... @crazymatt - `Position: absolute;` shouldn't be the problem because if it works in the bigger versions, it should work when scaling back up.  Thats how CSS media queries work.

Comment: I updated with the full menu css.  I realized it may be another element of the CSS menu.  Full and Condensed will be VERY similar..just different sizes.  Condensed is where everything changes.... but remember...THIS ONLY HAPPENS when expanding the menu and collapsing it back down via jquery.